# Cancel the autocomplete after I leave the field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way to stop the ui jQuery Autocomplete if the user leaves the page looking at the [Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) I see many things

```
.autocomplete( "destroy" )
.autocomplete( "disable" )
.autocomplete( "close" )
```

but how do I use them after a user leaves the field

```
$("#request_song").autocomplete({
  source: function(req, add){
    $.getJSON('<%= ajax_path("trackName") %>', req, function(data) {
      var suggestions = data.suggestions;
      add(suggestions);
    });
  },
  change: function() {
    var main = $('#main_content');
    main.empty().append("<img id=\"throbber\" src='/pre_config/css/images/throbber.gif' alt='Loading. Please wait.' />");
    $("#band_events").load("/load_events/"+ escape($('#request_artist').val()), successCallback );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind a `blur` event handler to the field (essentially a lost-focus event):

```
$("#request_song").blur(function(){
    // Using disable and close after destroy is redundant; just use destroy
    $(this).autocomplete("destroy");
});
```

Comment: can i add two selectors at the same time like $("#request_song", "#request_artist").blur(function(){

Comment: You were close: `$("#request_song, #request_artist").blur(function(){`